# Adding LWC in Record Page Layout Section

Tags: lightning-web-components, page-layout, lightning-events

Aside from nesting inside a visualforce, is there any way to add a LWC between sections in a page layout? Please take in consideration these Components will call events like getRecord, getRecordNotifyChange and ShowToastEvent.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't add Aura or LWC components into the page layout. In Lightning, you can create a Lightning Record Page, and display components in almost any section you like (just not in the page layout itself). In Classic, Lightning Out is your only option.

Comment: I believe dynamic forms allow mixing of components and field sections to give an experience where fields and LWCs can appear side by side.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, I thought as much. I'll try to convince the client to either leave at the of the page or add a new tab so I can use app builder.

Comment: Also, your ideia is not bad @Phil W, but it would create other problems in my case :/ Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hi @Phil W, were you able to add components and fields side by side in the same section on dynamic forms? If so, can you pls explain how?

Comment: Directly in a section, no, but you can have more sophisticated layouts with small sections.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it makes sense to consider adoption of Dynamic Forms (current standard object limitations may prevent it, of course).

It is worth considering that Salesforce's long term goal, as has been publicly stated, is to move most elements from Profiles to the favoured permission set and perm set group. I have also seen info from Salesforce suggesting a desire to entirely retire Profile due to its limitations compared with alternative, one-to-many metadata types like perm set groups.

Right now page layout assignments are one of the few elements still tied to the Profile. This dependency is effectively removed by adopting dynamic forms which themselves do not rely on page layouts (you can choose to have dependency on layout sections still, but I am not suggesting this usage).

Instead, these allow fields to be presented based on both permissions and configured visibility rules - expressions allowing a level of sophistication not possible with page layouts.

In addition, there is far more flexibility in mixing form sections with custom LWCs, which is why I suggest this approach.

You will find more information in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dynamic_forms_overview.htm&type=5), including the current state of play for standard object support.